# Active Menu Highlighter with Subpages?

Tags: menus, headers, child-pages

my question is...

---

I have 2 pages & 2 subpages in each page.
like:

page1

-->subpage1

-->subpage2

page2

-->subpage1

-->subpage2

& my Menu is       **Page1   page2**

Now if i select subpage1(from page1) means the page1 need to active and highlight the menu.
if i select subpage1(from page2) means it need to highlight page2 and page2 menu in active.

how to do this?
please help me to get rid of this problem.i need to implement in my wordpress website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To highlight page 1 and page 2 use `current-menu-parent` class

Answer (score 1):

It'll be done with CSS and an active class. Check the coding on the front end to see what wordpress has added for active page. On one setup we have the class **menu-item** and **current_page_item** is added so you could style those.